# how do i display a message of loading or search while a page is loading then hide the message and display the site?

Tags: jquery

here is a site i'm refering to:
http://www.graphicfirm.com/index.php

if you scroll down to the bottom and for example click on automotive while the pictures are being loaded you see a message that says searching.... and then when you click on a picture everything is kind of dimmed and you see the message loading...

how is this done with jquery/ajax?

correct me if im wrong but this is my best guess.

```
$.ajax({
       url: "ajax.php",
       type: "GET",
       dataType: "json",
       data: "attribute=myvalue",

        beforeSend: function()
        {

            $(".mymessage").show();
            //dim page
        },

        complete: function()
        {

            $(".mymessage").hide();
            //undim page
        },

        success: function(data)
        {

            //load data               

        }

});
```

if i got it right how would they be dimming the page?
if i got it wrong can you show me a sample?

thanks

Comment: That link points to an apache test page :)

Comment: try printfirm.com i dont know why it does that it doesnt do it for me

Comment: go to graphicfirm.com/index.php not index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how you should do this:

```
$(".mymessage").show();
$.ajax({
       url: "ajax.php",
       type: "GET",
       dataType: "json",
       data: "attribute=myvalue",
        success: function(data)
        {
           $(".mymessage").hide();
           //load data
        }
});
```

Put `$(".mymessage").show();` before ajax call and hide it right when the `success` occurs.

Comment: question is how do i hide or dim the entire page?

Comment: Assuming the whole page is wrapped inside a `div` like `<div id="wrapper">` you can do like this: `$("#wrapper").css({"opacity":"0.5"})` and then in `success` function of the ajax call reset it to 1 like this: `$("#wrapper").css({"opacity":"1"})`

Comment: thanks let me try it and i'll reply if i have any problems. thats exatly how i was tinking it would work but let me try it and see what happends.

Answer (score 3):

Look at: http://malsup.com/jquery/block/

This allows you to block the entire site while displaying a message to your user.